# How to assign a file to the FileField in Django?

Tags: django

How to assign a file to the FileField in Django?

I try:

```
from django.core.files import File
...
...
att_path = os.path.join(detach_dir, filename)

if not os.path.isfile(att_path):
    fp = open(att_path, 'wb')
    djangofile = File(fp)
    fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))

    user = User.objects.get(id=1)
    files = File.objects.create(src=djangofile, user=user)
    fp.close()
```

but I have this error:

> AttributeError: type object 'File' has no attribute 'objects'

models.py:

```
class File(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    src = models.FileField(upload_to="src")
```

Comment: dont give your model the same name as the class you're importing from django

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
class File(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    src = models.FileField(upload_to="src")
```

to:

```
class UserFile(models.Model):  # for example
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    src = models.FileField(upload_to="src")
```

and then create it like this:

```
files = UserFile.objects.create(src=djangofile, user=user)
```

`from django.core.files import File` is conflicting with `from yourapp.models import File`

[One example](http://www.nitinh.com/2009/02/django-example-filefield-and-imagefield/) on using `FileFields`.

Comment: Thanks. This fix this error but now my `src` field is empty after save. `files = FileStore.objects.create(src=djangofile, user=user)` - it seems that `djangofile` is incorrect

Comment: @user2307683 Have you printed the value of `att_path` right after this line `att_path = os.path.join(detach_dir, filename)`? Are you certain the path is correct?

Comment: This printed only name of file `dosinsu.png`. Not full path

Comment: @user2307683 I'm not familiar with processing email attachments sorry. That error doesn't seem django related.

Comment: @user2307683 I suggest you open another question about how to process the attachment with imaplib.

Comment: @user2307683 I just noticed, that you're opening the file with `'rb'` and you're actually trying to create a new file right? Have you tried with `'wb'`? (in the link you posted, in the code of your question it's `'wb'`)